# How do I access JAR classes from within my Clojure program?

Tags: java, clojure, compilation, noclassdeffounderror

I've been stuck for several days on something that I *know* I've gotten to work once before. I'm probably missing something obvious. Any help would be appreciated.

In my Clojure program, I want to access methods from classes originally written in Java. Let's use a specific example: org.infoml.jaxb.ObjectFactory. These classes are in a .jar file (`infoml-classes-1.0.jar`) that is a double-clickable Java application. If you open up the jar file, you see the folder for the top-level segment of the Java classes' package:

```
macscooter:infoml-classes-1.0 folder gw$ find . -print | sed -e 's;[^/]*/;|____;g;s;____|; |;g'
.
|____META-INF
| |____MANIFEST.MF
|____org
| |____infoml
| | |____infocardOrganizer  <<<<<< Java application's classes
| | | |____AFileFilter.class

      |  ... many classes omitted here

| | | |____UniqueContentListener.class
| | | |____UniqueContentModel.class
| | |____jaxb
| | | |____AgentContainerLocationType.class
| | | |____AgentType.class

      |  ... many classes omitted here

| | | |____ObjectFactory.class   <<<<<< HERE IT IS

      |  ... many classes omitted here

| | | |____TableRowType.class
| | | |____TableType.class
macscooter:infoml-classes-1.0 folder gw$
```

In my Clojure program, I import it (from file `cardmaker.clj`):

```
(ns infwb.cardmaker
  (:gen-class)
  (:import
   (javax.xml.bind  JAXBContext  JAXBException  Marshaller
            Unmarshaller)
    (org.infoml.jaxb        ContentAgentContainerLocationType
            InfomlFile  InfomlType  ObjectFactory  PType  <<<<<< HERE IT IS
            RichTextWithExactType
            SelectorsType
            SimpleRichTextType)
   (java.io  ByteArrayOutputStream IOException)))
```

When I print out the classpath that the REPL sees, it's there (as `infoml-classes-1.0.jar`):

```
infwb.cardmaker> (doseq [p (.getURLs (java.lang.ClassLoader/getSystemClassLoader))] (println (.getPath p)))
/Users/gw/tech/clojurestuff/cljprojects/infwb/src/
/Users/gw/tech/clojurestuff/cljprojects/infwb/test/
/Users/gw/tech/clojurestuff/cljprojects/infwb/classes/
/Users/gw/tech/clojurestuff/cljprojects/infwb/lib/clojure-1.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
/Users/gw/tech/clojurestuff/cljprojects/infwb/lib/clojure-contrib-1.2.0.jar
/Users/gw/tech/clojurestuff/cljprojects/infwb/lib/infoml-classes-1.0.jar  <<<<<< HERE IT IS
/Users/gw/tech/clojurestuff/cljprojects/infwb/lib/piccolo2dcore-1.3.jar
/Users/gw/tech/clojurestuff/cljprojects/infwb/lib/piccolo2dextras-1.3.jar
/Users/gw/tech/clojurestuff/cljprojects/infwb/lib/sxqj-beta2.jar
/Users/gw/tech/clojurestuff/cljprojects/infwb/lib/dev/clojure-1.2.0.jar
/Users/gw/tech/clojurestuff/cljprojects/infwb/lib/dev/swank-clojure-1.3.0-20110104.084027-21.jar
nil
infwb.cardmaker>
```

However, when I try to compile the file cardmaker.clj (by either C-c C-k or `(load-file "src/infwb/cardmaker.clj")`, I get the following exception:

```
Could not initialize class org.infoml.jaxb.ObjectFactory
  [Thrown class java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError]
```

I've gone as far as rebooting my machine to try to eliminate inadvertent crud as a source of the problem. I've researched several things on the Internet--no luck. I've looked at the MANIFEST.MF file for clues, and stripped the jar file down to just the classes I need. I've slept on it overnight twice now--still no solution.

Using existing Java classes from within Clojure is a useful thing to do. I'd appreciate the help that anyone might be able to give me. Thanks.

---

ADDENDUM: My problem was caused by a number of factors, including a missing jar file. @kotarak's answer was spot on. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried another notation for importing java-classes? Something like:
    (import '(packagename ClassName))

Comment: The `import` is fine. Have you tried to look beyond what emacs says? Maybe `ObjectFactory` itself needs another class, which is not found? Try loading your code in a plain repl to see the complete stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you `import` the classes is fine. Obviously the `ObjectFactory` class cannot be initialised because some other class it needs is not on the classpath. Lookup at the full stacktrace to find out which class is missing for `ObjectFactory` to work. As @mikera suggested, you can use `(import 'org.infoml.jaxb.ObjectFactory)` in the Repl to do that. (Unless emacs eats your stacktrace...)

Answer (score 3):

I am not 100% sure I fully get your question, but if you are simply trying to access your Java classes from a Clojure program, I would use [leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen). Here is roughly what you do once you have installed leiningen:

```
lein new cardmaker
cd cardmaker
lein deps
```

Put your jar file in the lib directory.

After this you will get a directory structure that looks like this:

```
├── README
├── classes
├── lib
│   ├── clojure-1.2.1.jar
│   └── infoml-classes-1.0.jar
├── project.clj
├── src
│   └── cardmaker
│       └── core.clj
└── test
    └── cardmaker
        └── test
            └── core.clj
```

Now you can import your Java classes in your Clojure program and have access to them via Clojure Java interop. Here is an example

```
(ns cardmaker.core
  (:import [java.util Blah Blah]))
```

To run this program, you have a bunch of different options. See the [leiningen docs](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/TUTORIAL.md). It looks like you are using emacs so see [swank clojure](https://github.com/technomancy/swank-clojure). Using leiningen in this way should resolve your classpath issues.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following code to import Java classes:

```
  (ns my.namespace
    (:import [java.io DataInputStream File FileInputStream BufferedInputStream])
    (:import [my.package MyClassOne MyClassTwo])
    ....
```

This should work providing the relevant Java classes are on the classpath (it's fine if they are in a .jar).

To test whether these are on the classpath you can also do the following at the REPL:

```
  (import 'my.package.MyClassOne)
```